# Intellij 2017.1 with python plugin does not show correct Quick Documentation

Tags: python, intellij-idea

It seems the quick docs for python have gone bad. screenshot1 is the from the print build-in function on 2016.3 and seems fine, while screenshot2 is from 2017.1
Am I missing something?

screenshot1:
[image]
screenshot2:
[image]

Comment: Hello Martin, It's expected behavior due to migration to type hints from typeshed project.

Comment: that's unfortunate. i think great convenience is lost. Is there an option to go back to the previous way?

Comment: @PyTony is there a plan to re-enable this functionality at some point - seems like a big regression.

Comment: started using kite.com    Replaces the doc pop-up window all together.

Comment: I tried kite but for some reason it didn't work out of the box for me so I uninstalled it. Was not really comfortable with it uploading my code to their cloud - thanks for the heads up though, not heard or it before.

Comment: ended up doing the same. still buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my mac pressing alt+space give me the definition. Not as nice but functional:

[image: screenshot of intellij]